# Most efficient way to calculate every L2 distance between vectors of vector array A and vectors of vector array B?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I need to implement an algorithm. But it takes a lot of time to compute and I need to make it as fast as possible.

Right now I have two numpy arrays:

Array A -> 2000 vectors of 512 elements,

Array B -> 1000 vectors of 512 elements.

I need to calculate every single distance between the vectors from Array A and Array B. Right now, I take 1 vector from array A, and calculate it's distances to all vectors in Array B as follows:

`np.sum(np.abs(B-A[0])**2,axis=-1)**(0.5)`

But using this I have to loop for 2000 cycles and it takes a lot of time.

Any alternatives?

Comment: @Mad Physicist, this question is different because it's about all pairwise distances, not just the distance between two vectors.

Comment: @orlp. Does `cdist` return what you are looking for? Are you not asking for a 1000x2000 matrix of distances?

Comment: I only used what @orlp proposed and it provided what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) solves exactly this problem.